# The Class Firebase doesn't exist

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

After Following all the steps of Firebase Quickstart,even got connected to it,I don't have the Firebase class.
basically I cant use function like

```
Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
```

many of my import statements are unused

[image: This is my current status]

Comment: Have you added the Firebase dependencies? Have you added the Firebase class to your imports?

Comment: Are you following the [correct documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup)?

Comment: The statement you use `Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);` is for the Firebase 2.x SDK (firebase.com). The Assistant (side-panel on the right) is made for using with Firebase 3.x (firebase.google.com). You'll have to pick one or the other, mixing them is not possible.

Comment: To downvoters: If you downvote, at least explain. Yes, this question may belong to http://superuser.com/ or to http://android.stackexchange.com/, but it is a good question.

Comment: Such a good question. I'm also facing this problem. So strange that it is downvoted. Something IS really missed in the documentation

Answer (score 4):

Well, I'm writing in the context of your problem. The latest version of the Google's Android Studio doesn't have a Cloud section in Project Structure so you can't be able to make changes. However in order to resolve your issue just write these things manually:

- In the manifest file declare the permission for INTERNET.
- Now comes the resolution for your problem:
  -> **Go to the build.gradle(Module:app) and declare the following 
       compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'**
- Sync the project

Now you'll be able to see the Firebase class which you had been searching for. 
All the best in your endeavour!

Answer (score 0):

You set up Firebase database but refereing firebase client in your code.
Follow how to write and read data here https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/

Simply

```
// Write a message to the database
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("message");

myRef.setValue("Hello, World!");
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed Firebase?
Check if you have declared the dependency right.

This documentation is clear, try following these steps
https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/quickstart.html

Answer (score -1):

Go to the Android manifest file add this line

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

and then add this dependency in the `build.gradle` file:

```
implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'
```